# How to query Reference field in Firestore Android?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Here I have "Device Document" which has reference to "OS document"

I want to get Devices which are having latest OS

[image: It is how os Document looks like]

[image: This is my Devices Document]

Please help me with Querying

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. What did you already try?

Comment: Rightly said by @FrankvanPuffelen. If you want the answer you yourself have to do some hard work and write the code. And then if you face some here do ask. So, first do and show what code you have written PratishJage

Answer (score 0):

You should keep latest 'OS' of 'device' in each 'devices' documents.

because firebase recommended to get data that needed in single query .

Ref: [How is Cloud Firestore structured?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v_hR4K4auoQ)